# SELECT last row grouped by account and assigned number

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table "Log" 
My game server inserts a record into this table when someone login the server, then inserts a second record when they logout.
What I want to do is create a query to count the number of people logged in.

the main data that gets inserted to the table "Log"

**When they Login:**

```
[Type] = 0
[Player1] = Their account ID
[Value2] = a random number which matches the logout row when they logout
[Value3] = 0
```

**When they Logout:**

```
[Type] = 1
[Player1] = Their account ID
[Value2] = a random number which matches the login row when they logout
[Value3] = some random number
```

Is there a way I can count the last "Player1" of each account and check if "Type" = 0 which means that account is logged in then echo the result.

The result I'm looking for would pull the last record of every account an count them.

Note: everytime an account logs in and out it inserts them 2 records so if 1 account logs in 20 times there would be 40 records in "Log"

Comment: The problem is how would you know which one is first or last on what basis you want to sort them. You are not storing any time or date column which will help in sorting.

Comment: Sorry it adds a date too.. under [Date]

Comment: I'm confused.... You want a count of the people currently logged in at time query is run per "What I want to do is create a query to count the number of people logged in" but then your subject says, "SELECT last row grouped by account and assigned number"  Do you want the count or last row by account?  What do you expect in the "RESULT set?"

Comment: I want to count the last of each [Player!] where [Type] is 1 and [Value3] 0 where there isn't a logout row of [Value2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to count all rows with type 0 for which there doesn't exist any type 1 row with the same player and a later date:

```
select count(*) as number_of_logged_in
from log l
where Type = 0 -- 0 meaning log on event
-- and [Value3] = 0 -- maybe this should be included
and not exists (
    select 1 from log 
    where Player1 = l.Player1 
      and type = 1  -- 1 meaning log out event
      and date > l.date
      -- and [Value2] = l.[Value2] -- maybe this should be included
);
```

I found your problem statement a bit confusing as you say you want to count the number of people that are logged in, but then you say *I want to count the last of each [Player!] where [Type] is 1* which seems to be the opposite. It's also not clear to me why the random number would be important - if the last recorded type for a user is 0 then they should be considered as logged in, or?

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd76e/1) with some demo data

Comment: You'd need to match on the random number too, since a player could log in, then log out, then log in again, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm feeling stupid.. I trust that you are correct, but I don't quite follow why the random number is important. If there isn't any type 1 (logout) row with a later date then the user should be logged in - or am I missing something?

Comment: I was thinking about the case where a logout event wasn't recorded, but I suppose that would still show up. Or when you want to do the opposite (actually link a logout to a login).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ah, ok. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: the random number isn't important I was just trying to give as much info to my problem as I can.
What is important is Value2 & Type as Value2 match the login & logout rows for each set of records & Type tells you if its login or out.

Comment: @ToXiC Good. If you need to random number to match you can uncomment the lines I left commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want list of the all the logged in players names,so you can try using the `ROW_NUMBER()` to get what you want,

```
;WITH CTE AS(
         SELECT
             Player1 AS LoggedInPlayer,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Player1 ORDER BY datecolumn Asc) As LoggedValue
         FROM 
             yourtable
  ) 

  SELECT 
        * 
  FROM 
      CTE 
  WHERE  
      LoggedValue = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that all logins and logouts are stored in `Log` without gaps, you can simply count them and if there's a difference you know, that the player is currently logged in.

```
SELECT logins.player1, logouts.cnt - logins.cnt
FROM
    (select player1, count(*) as cnt from Log where type = 0 group by player1) as logins
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (select player1, count(*) as cnt from Log where type = 1 group by player1) as logouts
ON  (logins.player1 = logouts.player1)
WHERE logins.cnt > logouts.cnt or logouts.player1 is null
```

You need the `left outer join`, if the player logged in one time and never logged out. Sorry, if you encounter syntax issues. I just wrote this without testing and usually work on a Teradata System and the SQL Dialect there. But as the SQL given here is plain Ansi, it should work on any database.

Comment: For SQL Server you need to change the group by clauses to `group by player1` or you'll get an error: _Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference._